# GNU Coreutil Date (outputs numbers in CLI but not in bash script)

Tags: bash, date, ubuntu, gnu-coreutils

Whenever I run a command in bash CLI, I get the right output

```
date +%Y%-m%d%j%M%S
202111063103528
```

However, when I run this in a bash script, I am not getting a simple number that I can use in a later variable. I'm ultimately wanting to use this to backup old CSV files I've generated.  e.g.

```
#Doesn't print out correct date
DATE='date +%Y%-m%d%j%M%S'
echo $DATE

# Ultimately, wanting to feed that $DATE string here 
if [ -f "$CSV_OUTFILE" ]; then
          echo "CSV file already exists. Renaming $CSV_OUTFILE to $CSV_OUTFILE.$DATE"
          mv $CSV_OUTFILE $CSV_OUTFILE.$DATE
          exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned the string `date +%Y%-m%d%j%M%S` to `$DATE`. It contains a space, so using `$DATE` in `mv` without double quotes expands it to two words.

Use backquotes instead of quotes to capture the output of a command:

```
DATE=`date +%Y%-m%d%j%M%S`
```

Or, better, use the `$(...)` syntax (better because it can be nested):

```
DATE=$(date +%Y%-m%d%j%M%S)
```